# What did I do wrong in this questions (sample proportions)?

Tags: probability, statistics

Thirteen percent of students took a college remedial course in 2016-2017. Assuming this is still true, what is the probability (to 3dp), that in 350 randomly selected students, that less than 40 take the remedial course?

I treated it as a sample proportion question where X = p̂/n. Then, I let:
X=40, n=350, p̂=0.13

where p̂ ~ N{p, [p(1-p)]/n}

So then, I did:

P(p̂ < 40/350), let Z~N(0,1)

= P{Z < (4/35 - 0.13)/root[(0.13)(0.87)/350]} to normalise it, but it gives me the wrong answer. Where did I make a mistake?

Someone told me I should answer it by just using normal distributions with E(x)=np and Var(X)=np(1-p). Why would this method be correct but my method incorrect? Is using sample proportions incorrect? How should I know if I should use sample proportions or just normal distributions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Assuming $p = .13$ take remedial course, number $X$ out of  $n=350$ should have $X \sim\mathsf{Binom}(n=350,p=.13)$ and you seek $P(X \le 39).$ You can use software or standardization, normal approx, and printed normal CDF table to evaluate that. In R, where `pbinom` is binomial CDF, code `pbinom(39, 350, .13)` returns $0.1704741,$ which you can round to 3 places (about the accuracy you'll get rounding to use printed table. // Your method is not wrong, but is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to follow your working, but I think the way you are approaching the question is incorrect. When we are dealing with sample sizes in large populations, we assume that our sample proportion, in this case $p̂=0.13$ as our population proportion as well. So, we can then treat the problem as binomial distribution, where:

$n = 350$
$x = 40$
$p̂ = 0.13$

Knowing this, I encourage you to give this problem a go yourself. If you still cannot solve it then let me know and I can provide the answer.

As you are new to Stack Exchange, it is a good idea to familiarize yourself with MathJax, as questions may attract negative votes if they are not formatted properly. You can find the MatJax reference below:

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)